# Safari doesn't "save" google results pages

Tags: macos, safari, mojave

If I

- open a new tab
- use the omnibar to google for something
- click on a google result
- press back

I get sent to the new tab page, not the google results page.

Also, the google results page doesn't show up in history.

How do I stop that from happening?

I want google results pages to be treated like all other (normal) pages.

Comment: Are you using iOS or MacOS? Are you in private mode?

Comment: @Theologin macOS, not private mode

Comment: Try changing your homepage to About:Blank and set your browser to open your homepage when you open a new tab. Check to see if this still reproduces the same issue.